# Why does a responsive image work by itself but not in an existing web page?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

Here's what works:

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>CSS Test</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 14.0" />

    <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
        <img src="graphics/mamdesk.jpg" alt="Mam" class="responsive" >
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS

```
.responsive {
    max-width: 60vw;
    max-height: 60vh;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

But when I try to apply that exact code to an image on an existing website, it seems to have no effect. The CSS is simply ignored.

Here's the structure of the existing document:

HTML

```
<section>
        <nav>
WHAT I SNIPPED IS AN UNORDERED LIST THAT WORKS FINE
        </nav>

        <img src="graphics/mamdesk.jpg" alt="Mam" class="responsive" >

</section>
```

The additional CSS:

```
nav
{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* Container for flexboxes */
section {
  display: flex;
}
```

So, clearly, something above is stopping the responsive image from working, but I'm not smart enough to figure out what it is.

I thought it might be that "section" in CSS, but if I leave that out then the photo appears under the unordered list rather than to the side of it.

The existing website is here: https://www.korat-legal.com

What I want to do is make the image responsive so that it will shrink or expand depending on the window size.

Comment: Neither the class "responsive" on the image or the selector ".responsive" in your style sheet is present on your live version. Probably a cache issue?

Comment: I'm not editing the live version, but the source that's on my own machine. I'm using BBEdit and their preview facility to review the result of the code changes.

Comment: do use media queries? Cause I can not see it here.

Comment: I do not use media queries. The CSS just expands or contracts the image based on the screen size. You can see it working well on another web page here: https://www.mgnewman.com/rtw//Afghanistan.php

Answer (score 0):

It was a missing curly brace in the css file.